# Check if button has been disabled or not in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

To set a button or input as disabled or not by:

```
<button ng-disabled="true">My Button</button>
```

Now, my question how to check either `My Button` has been disabled or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your controller you should have a variable

```
$scope.buttonDisabled = true;
```

then in your file

```
<button ng-disabled="buttonDisabled">My Button</button>
```

then your ng-if

```
ng-if="buttonDisabled"
```

Comment: I agree with your answer, since we can manipulate the logic in controller. So I mark as right answer. Thanks!